# Can I recover my saved-over TIF file?

Tags: tiff, retouching, file-recovery

While retouching I saved my file as a tif and then flatten it and saved as a jpeg. I accidentally saved the tif again while it was flattened with no layers. Is there a way to recover my tif file with the layers?

Comment: If you are lucky, the application saved the file as a new file, then erased the old version and renamed the new. This leaves the previous version as an erased file on the disk, and it can be recovered using "unerase" utilities. But best ask in [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/), you'll get more informed answers. And since this is purely a computer problem, state operating system, disk type, etc.... when you ask the question.

Comment: Also, the filesystem might have allocated new space for the new copy and didn't yet reuse the sectors where the old version was. Slim chance though....

Comment: @rachandboneman If it does save new/erase old/rename new this is implicit, since the old version is still on the disk when the new one is saved.

Comment: vtc b/c This is a question about file recovery, not photography per se.

Comment: Btw, I don't know what app you are using but in the one I use (Gimp) flattening is automatic (and not done on the current image) when "exporting " to JPEG.

Comment: @Xiota Not if you do "Save", only of you do "Save as...", so in the case at hand it would not have helped (assuming a *open XCF/edit/flatten/export to Jpeg/save* sequence).

Comment: @Xiota Ctrl-E will bluntly re-export the file if you loaded it from a non-XCF format.

Comment: @xenoid Seems like they're purposefully trying to make people lose data.

Answer (score 1):

If you are still in the program, you might be able to undo.

If you have some kind of automatic backups or versioning filesystem installed, you might be able to recover from that.

Otherwise, sorry, no.

Comment: Can also search the Google machine for file recovery programs.

Comment: @xiota Unlilkely if the file has been saved over.

Comment: Most programs in modern operating systems don't *actually* over write files when they "save over" files.

Comment: Good odds if the filesystem is journalled.

Comment: Bad odds that anyone who asks the question above knows what journalling is, must less has their file system journaled.